# Combine results from multiple Node.js API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js

New to Node.js here. I'm looking for the correct way to make N asynchronous API calls from within another function, and combining their results to use further downstream. In my case, N would be reasonably small and blocking for their execution not too bad.

In synchronous execution the implementation for combine() below should work.

If I only needed the results from one API call it would be straightforward to implement the following logic in a callback function supplied to callAPI(). Where I stumble is when I need all the results combined before before executing foo(total, [...args]).

I looked into `async.whilst` but wasn't able to get that to work. I'm skeptical if that actually is the correct fit to my needs. I've also looked into `Promises` which seems to be the correct lead but it would be nice to get reassurances before crawling into that cavernous rabbit hole. Be it that `Promises` is the correct way, which module is the standard to use in `Node.js` projects?

```
var http = require('http');

function callAPI(id) {
    var options = {
        host: 'example.com',
        path: '/q/result/'.concat(id)
    }

    var req = http.get(options, (res) => {
        var body = [];
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body.push(chunk);
        }).on('end', () => {
            body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
            return body;
        }).on('error', (err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    });
}

function combine(inputs) {

    var total = 0;
    for (i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        total += callAPI(inputs[i]['id']);
    };
    console.log(total);

    // call some function, foo(total, [...args])
}
```

Edit 1:

I attempted to follow samanime's answer below and modify the API call to return a Promise. See:

```
function callAPI(id) {
    return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var options = {
            host: 'example.com',
            path: '/q/result/'.concat(id)
        }

        var req = http.get(options, (res) => {
            var body = [];
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body.push(chunk);
            }).on('end', () => {
                body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
                resolve(body);
            }).on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    });
}

function combine(inputs) {

    var combined = [];
    for (i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        total += callAPI(inputs[i]['id']);
            .then(result => {
                combined.push(result);
            });
    };
    var total = combined.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    console.log(total);

    // call some function, foo(total, [...args])
}
```

This seems to get me halfway there. If I `console.log(combined)` inside the `then()` block I can see the list building up with results from the API calls. However, I still can't access the complete `combined` at the "end" of the `for` loop. Can I attach a callback to something to run after the full list has been built? Is there a better way?

Edit 2 (My solution - per Patrick Roberts suggestion)

```
function callAPI(id) {
    return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var options = {
            host: 'example.com',
            path: '/q/result/'.concat(id)
        }

        var req = http.get(options, (res) => {
            var body = [];
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body.push(chunk);
            }).on('end', () => {
                body = parseInt(Buffer.concat(body));
                resolve(body);
            }).on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    });
}

function combine(inputs) {
    var combined = [];
    Promise.all(inputs.map(input => callAPI(input.id)))
        .then((combined) => {
            var total = combined.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
            // foo(total, [...args])
        });
};
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636542/loop-through-asynchronous-request/44636736#44636736 Its exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your edit is looking a lot better, but try this:

```
function callAPI(id) {
  return Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var options = {
      host: 'example.com',
      path: '/q/result/' + id
    }

    http.get(options, (res) => {
      var body = [];
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body.push(chunk);
      }).on('end', () => {
        body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
        resolve(body);
      }).on('error', reject);
    });
  });
}

function combine(inputs) {
  Promise.all(inputs.map(input => callAPI(input.id))).then((combined) => {
    // completed array of bodies
    console.log(combined);
    // foo(combined.length, [...args]);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you can just chain together a bunch of promises, passing the data along.

Basically something like:

```
const combined = [];
asyncOne()
  .then(result => { combined.push(result); return asyncTwo())
  .then(result => { combined.push(result); return asyncThree())
  // and so on
```

As long as each function returns a promise, you'll be all set.

If you want to run them in parallel, use `Promise.all()`, which will do the same thing for you:

```
Promise.all([asyncOne(), asyncTwo(), asyncThree() /* , etc */])
  .then(combined => /* combined is an array with the results of each */)
```

This is by far the preferred pattern for this sort of thing.

Answer (score -1):

I would add a counter that keeps track of remaining API calls. Whenever an API call finishes, decrement and if its 0, you're done.

```js
const numCalls = 10;
let remaining = numCalls;
let data = [];

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function ajax() {
    // Simulate ajax with a setTimeout for random amount of time.
    setTimeout(() => {
        // This is the callback when calling http.get
        data.push(getRandomInt(0, 10)); // Some data from server
        if (--remaining <= 0) {
            // Am I the last call? Use data.
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.length);
        }
    }, getRandomInt(1000, 3000));
}

for (let i = 0; i < numCalls; i++) {
    ajax();
}
```

Comment: It's typically bad practice to mix your application logic with asynchronous control-flow logic, this is why `Promises` were created, and before them, libraries like `async`.

Comment: Sure. It all depends right. Use Promises if you can. I would argue however, that calling resolve/reject at certain points in your code is asynchronous control-flow logic (but neater) we're still mixing it with app. logic.

Comment: I'm talking about _counting_ internal callbacks, and _conditional_ execution of consumer callbacks inside of your application logic. Of course you'll have to `resolve()`, `reject()`, or `callback()` or `next()` depending on the asynchronous control flow you choose to go with, but it's much cleaner than re-inventing the wheel with your own attempt at control-flow logic.