# Node.js request - handling multiple POST requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use request library to communicate with other servers via API. But now I need to send multiple (10 or more) POST requests at the same time and move further only if all responsens will be correct. Usually syntax looks a bit like this:

```
var options = {
url: "",
method: "POST",
header: {...},
body: {...}
};

request(options, function(err,response,body)
{
}
```

But now I've got an array of objects instead of a single options variable. Is there a way to do this? Or maybe there is another library able to handle the issue.

EDIT:

```
var arrayOfIds = [];
const requests = [];
for(var i in range){
   var options = {} // here goes all bodies and headers to send
   requests.push( // push a request to array dynamically 
    request(options, function(err,response,body){
     if(!err && response.statusCode == 201){
      arrayOfIds.push(body.id);
     }
   }));

Promise.all(requests)
.then(function(res){
    console.log(arrayOfIds); // this is empty
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through asynchronous request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636542/loop-through-asynchronous-request)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches to solve this:

- async library, method parallel
- Promise.all

To switch your request to promises, use additionaly to `request` module - `request-promise`. In code it will look like this:

```
const request = require('request-promise');

// Note, you don't assign callback here
const promises = [
  request.post({...}),
  request.post({...}),
  request.post({...})
];

// And then you simply do Promise.all
Promise.all(promises).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. And what If I don't know exact number of request? Should I use a regular loop to fulfill const promises array?

Comment: Just fill them dynamically, it's not a problem.

Comment: One last question: all of those request should send back to me an ids of objects which I've just created remotly on another server. I've created an array of ids and tried to populate it pushing a body.id value received if everything is correct. However it doesn't work and after Promise.all I get only an empty array. Do you know how to fix it? I've edited my initial code to show you everything

Comment: @Jacek717 Promise.all returns array of arrays. If you're sure you receive empty response - search for mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Add options object