# How to run for in loop synchrously in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I am running a for in loop and calling a REST API inside for in loop.So suppose userArray contains 5 users, then API is getting called once, getting hello five times.So how to run the API call inside loop 5 times in node js

```
for(user in userArray){
   var result=apiddetails.getuserdetails(user);
   console.log(result);
   console.log("hello"); 
}
```

Comment: you should make a wait inbetween API calls.

Comment: do you really need to use `for in` loop? do you really need to call it sync? you can do something like this tho

    `const results = Promise.all(userArray.map(apiddetails.getuserdetails))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through asynchronous request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44636542/loop-through-asynchronous-request)

Comment: yes similar though i did not want to use setTimeInterval , i wanted a robust few lines code Promise.all as told helped  with few lines modification in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's solution using **promises.**

```
var promises = [];
for(user in userArray){
   var promises.push[apiddetails.getuserdetails(user)]; //asumming you are returning promise from this function 
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: This solution, while correct, my change the order of the replies, no?

Comment: No 1st call value will be at values[0] position and 2nd call value will be at values[1] and so on

Comment: Yes, I [found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) it: "Returned values will be in order of the Promises passed, regardless of completion order."

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **async-await**

```
for(user in userArray){
   var result = (async function(){
      return await apiddetails.getuserdetails(user);
   })(user); //pass user as the argument
   console.log(result);
   console.log("hello"); 
}
```